# Route connections made to port 80 to a non-standard web server port (with or without a domain)

Tags: networking, domain

My ISP blocks the use of port 80 for "user security and safety" (stupid cox), but I still want to host a web server from my home, so I used a non-standard port (8080).  Is there any way of me to make requests from a domain using port 80 that get content from the non-standard port (8080)?

Comment: Sorry I can't put this as a comment due to lack of rep. Most decent routers have the ability to do port redirection, wherein upon a request to a particular port, it can route that request to a specified port at the LAN device. This would be useless to you though if your ISP is blocking port 80 all together, because the request to port 80 would never reach your router. If your ISP is blocking port 80 completely, you're going to need your own domain that people can make requests to, instead of making requests to your ISP IP address. Then, using DNS records on that domain you could probably use S

Comment: 2nd part of @SeanMissingham comment "you could probably use SRV records to work around your problem. https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20use%20srv%20records"

Answer (score 0):

Requests aren't made from a domain, but to an IP address.

So lets say your webserver was accessible via 222.222.222.222:8080, then the browser *must* make the request to that IP address and that port.

If it tries to go to 222.222.222.222:80, it will be blocked as you have discovered.  However, there is no step before this that you can use to cause the browser to pick another port.  It would need to get access to 80 for your server to redirect the request to 8080.

Your best option is to advertise the link with the port 8080

http://222.222.222.222:8080